# Implement caching Spring method level annotations vs Hibernate second level cache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching

I am working on implementing caching of certain static data.

I have two approaches :

- Use method level caching using Spring framework annotations.
- Enable 2nd level cache so hibernate manages caching of the data

Which of these approaches works best ?
What are the things I must consider ?

Comment: I think it will be hard to answer your first question, as I think that may be highly opinionated.  However, one thing you may consider in Hibernate caching is that it can effect how/when the data gets written.  My group canned Hibernate because it has a tendency to postpone writes to the DB in order to try and "optimize" them.  We would see code run, expect the DB to reflect the changes, but they were not there.  This is configurable behavior, but non-the-less something to consider.

Comment: @CodeChimp: that's not how the Hibernate 2nd-level cache works. It caches reads but not writes. Transactional semantics are always respected, with or wthout cache.

Comment: @JBNizet +1 to you, good sir, for teaching me something.  Found this link, if anyone is interested, that discusses 2nd level caching in Hibernate, with examples, as well as a link to a discussion on 1st level caching, again with examples:  http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/02/how-hibernate-second-level-cache-works/

Answer (score 5):

If all things equals consider prefering the Spring caching of method call results, the reason being that it's simpler to reason about caching at the level of the service layer.

The Hibernate second level cache works fine but it is in my opinion harder to reason about and it has more pitfalls. For example it does NOT work for queries, only for find by Ids or the loading of lazy associations.

Actually the loading of lazy associations is OFF by default, and needs to be enabled with a hibernate specific annotation at the collection level.

To query the results of queries, you need to use the query cache too, which only caches Id's and queries that return primitive values only. The Ids of the cached query are then resolved against the second level cache.

In both cases and with caches in general, the problem is usually to find the right moment to invalidate the cache.  Both ways allows to configure expiration and max number of elements/memory at the level of the cache provider such as ehcache.

For clearing the cache explicitly, Spring provides `@CacheEvict` method annotation, for comparison here is the recommended way for [clearing the Hibernate second level cache](http://java.dzone.com/tips/clearing-hibernate-second-leve).

Also have a look at this very well written blog post: [Truly Understanding the Hibernate Second Level and Query caches](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html).

Comment: +1 for explanation. I agree with you. My first thoughts were, if I were to use Spring, there is more programmatic control and that seemed reasonable. I will go through the links you have mentioned.

Comment: I would have given the exact inverse advice, precisely because with Hibernate, you don't have to invalidate the cache by yourself. If you write or delete an entity (through the Hibernate API), the cache will automatically be kept up-to-date or invalidated. That's not the case with Spring cache, which you'll have to explicitely invalidate every time you modify data that is being cached (and are aware of it).

Comment: how about child records that is associated in the hibernate object mappings you can not cache them with spring and also hibernate caches queries  if you configure similar to below                                                                                 <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
            maxElementsInMemory="10000"
            timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />                                                             and by setting cachable to TRUE .setCacheable(true)